# how to get the respective value from a database table where one of the column values are displayed in a list view

Tags: android

I have created a table named train_table in SQLite database with 3 columns. they are train_id, train_no and train_name. Now, i wrote a class in which i displayed the train_name in a list view. how do i get the related train_no in the next page? can anyone help me in sorting this problem.?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a `ListActivity`, the fourth parameter in the `onListItemClick` signature is the row id of the record in your table:

```
onListItemClick(ListView  l, View  v, int position, long id)
```

You can use this id to get the full record (all three column fields). The following SQLite statement could be called by a method you create to query the database for the record:

```
select * from train_table where train_id = id
```

If you're not using a ListActivity then I'm assuming you have set up a `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` for the `ListView`, in which case you'd have the following function defined:

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?>  parent, View  view, int position, long id)
```

In this case you would still use the id to get your record.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably "next page" you mean another view?

You could (assuming that the train_names are unique) create another SQLite query to re-read the database and retrieve the train_id into a local variable before switching to the "next page" view.